# Display elements from List<int> using inheritance

Tags: c#, list, class, inheritance, element

I'm fairly new to c# so i want to ask how can i display my list which i've created in a different class using ihneritance? Is it even possible? If not, how can i make this work? Right now the numbers im adding in the Pirmas_ivedimas class dissapear once i start to use my other class. My code:

```
class Pirmas_ivedimas //Class where im adding my list
{
    public int n, skaicius;
    public List<int> skaiciai = new List<int>();
    public void Iveskite()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Kiek skaiciu noresite ivesti?");
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Iveskite skaicius:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            skaicius = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            skaiciai.Add(skaicius);
        }
    }
}

class Skaiciu_sarasas:Pirmas_ivedimas //Class where i want to display my list
{
    public void skaiciuSarasas()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ivesti skaiciai:" + skaiciai.Count);
        skaiciai.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a [mcve]? You should be able to access the list in the child class.

Answer (score 0):

Without an example it is difficult to help you. If you are making an instance of your Skaiciu_sarasas class, that does not mean that you create an instance of your Pirmas_ivedimas class

The functionality to obtain the data should be implemented in the child class. You could implement the functionality to print the list in the parent class "Pirmas_ivedimas". To access this functionality from the child, you use Base.NameOfYourPrintFunction()